# Does Amazon Corretto supports JCE?

Tags: java, corretto

Currently, I am using Oracle JDK with JCE support. I am planning to move from oracle JDK to Amazon Corretto.

Just wanted to know whether Amazon Corretto supports JCE (Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8).

Comment: Since OpenJDK 8u161, unlimited cryptography has been enabled as default. See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html#JDK-8170157 As a result, Amazon Corretto also supports the unlimited cryptographic policy. Please let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Those releasenotes apply to _Oracle_ (and previously Sun) build(s). _OpenJDK_ builds never had the limited crypto policy in the first place -- although Coretto doesn't go back far enough for this to matter.

Answer (score 2):

Following what James said in the comment, the answer is yes it does.

Since OpenJDK 8u161, unlimited cryptography has been enabled as default. See oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/… As a result, Amazon Corretto also supports the unlimited cryptographic policy.